# Programmatically change background Color of FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, material-design

I tried setBackgroundTintList method but it requires min api 21 which is not most of programmers want. I want to change bgcolor of FloatingActionButton but programmatically with maintaining backward compatibility.
Is there any way or workaround?

Comment: You can try setBackgroundColor(int color) .

Comment: I tried it does not work as it overrides with theme color

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
mFab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(your color in int));
```

For example:

```
fabAdd.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.main_screen_status_bar)));
```

Comment: Guys my question was how to do with minSdk 15 as I mentioned setBackgroundTintList method requires min api 21

Answer (score 0):

If you use the support libraries in your build:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.2.1'
```

and in your class import this:

```
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
```

you should be able to call:

```
setBackgroundTintList
```

You will also need to use the support versions of Widgets in your layout files.

I think you could also use the [DrawableCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html) class, but I don't have any experience with it.